# Variable for Figure Number

Tags: graphics, captions

The package `\usepackage{titling}` allows me to set the `\title` in the preamble, and call the title in my paper using `\thetitle`.

I was wondering if there was something similar regarding figures and figure numbers.

For example, if I add a figure into the middle of my essay, I need to go through the text and changing all instances of "Figure X" into "Figure Y", and "Figure Y" into "Figure Z" etc.

Is there a way to associate figure numbers with a command, so that I can call the figure number, by doing something along the lines of `some text \somecommand some text`, where using `\somecommand`  will become "Figure X", depending on the figure's number?

I am using `\usepackage{graphicx}` to add images:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to hardcode the figure numbers by hand. Instead, you can put a label in your figure with, `\label{myLabel}` command in your figure environment. Then, you can cite your figure with `\ref{myLabel}` command throughout the document, this command gives you the number of the figure.
Example:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{myLabel}
\end{figure}

According to Figure~\ref{myLabel},...
```

This code will give an output like "According to Figure X,..." after the figure environment, where X will be the desired figure number. And if you insert/delete figures in the middle of the document, LaTeX recalculates the figure numbers automatically.

Note that `~` character is used before the `\ref` command to put an unbreakable space between "Figure" and its number.

You can check
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Referencing_Figures
for more information.